# How to achieve multi-processing in, consuming kafka messages without partitioning the topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My topic has only a single partition but I need to achieve multi processing.
I have a huge number of messages produced asynchronously and I want to read all those messages asynchronously and commit each message.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK you cannot achieve parallel processing without having more than one partition (i.e. at least two). 
In Kafka, partitions are the level of parallelism. Furthermore, the more partitions there are in a Kafka cluster, the higher the throughput one can achieve.

A Kafka topic is divided into a number of partitions which enables parallelism by splitting the data across multiple brokers. Multiple partitions enable multiple consumers to read from a topic in parallel. Therefore, in order to achieve parallel processing you need to partition your topic into more than one partitions.

In order to increase the number of partitions of an existing topic you can simply run

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic topicName --partitions 40
```

*This won't move existing data, though*

**Note on consumers, consumer groups and partitions**
 
If you have N partitions, then you can have up to N consumers within the same consumer group each of which reading from a single partition. When you have less consumers than partitions, then some of the consumers will read from more than one partition. Also, if you have more consumers than partitions then some of the consumers will be inactive and will receive no messages at all.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos Myrianthous for clarifying, But should I assign the partition number for each consumer? And how does the commit takes place for each partition. I need to manually commit the message after performing some action, If the message is not commited I will read it again. This is my usecase. If there is only one consumer and partition number is not given , will there be parallelism? If so , how is it been taken care? Don't mind I have many doubts regarding this.

Comment: @kkk You don't have to define the partition for each consumer. You just need to make sure that your consumers belong to the same consumer group. Regarding your question about offsets, you'll have to set `enable.auto.commit` to `false`, and then manually commit the offset when you want to.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Giorgos Myrianthous

Comment: Hi @Giorgos Myrianthous, As you said I created kafka partitions, but when I run multiple consumers all the consumers are reading the same message of all the partitions. Here goes my sample code.

from kafka import KafkaClient, SimpleConsumer
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from sys import argv
import time
consumer = KafkaConsumer("abc", group_id='my-group', bootstrap_servers=['my-server'])

   for message in consumer:
       #time.sleep(6)
       print "PARTITION "+str(message[1])+" OFFSET: "+str(message[2])+"\t MSG: "+str(message[4])
       consumer.commit()

Comment: @kkk Can you please ask a different question on SO as I believe this should be a different problem.

Comment: Hi @Giorgos Myrianthous, Here goes my question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665042/kafka-python-consumers-re-reading-all-the-part